# node.js проблема при клонирование через спред оператор

Tags: javascript, node.js

Тестирую метод который принимае параметр поля которого нужно эмулировать, создаю дефолт обьект для эмуляции, так как обьект нужно будет использовать много раз в каждом тесте клонирую его используя спред оператор, то есть каждый раз создается новый обьект, проверил себя выполнив тестовый код в консоли, запускаю тесты и вижу что на логе 1 дефолт обьект пустой а уже на логе 2 поле params заполенено, не могу понять почему, я клонирую дефолт обьект и работаю уже с клоном, почему он изменятеся , где ошибка у меня???

[image: мой код теста]

[image: дефолт обьект]

[image: проверял работу спред оператора]

[image: вывод после запуска тестов]

Comment: Так вы клонируете внешний объект, а вложенный объект в обоих объектах един. Как объекты, так и массивы, собственно, работают одинаково.

Comment: `let c={c:1}, b={c}, a={...b}; b.c.d=1; console.log(a) //{ c: { c:1, d:1 } }`

Comment: блин точно, спасибо огромное пол дня голову ломал, это нужно что то типа глубокого клонирования применить илинужное поле переназначать

Comment: Пожалуйста, добавляйте код текстом, а не изображением, чтобы отвечающим было легче копировать и тестировать фрагменты.